# Laravel fluent update return id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I found there is insert_get_id for insert by using fluent driver.
Is it anywhere for update to get id ?

I have check query.php, there is only function for insert_get_id ? 
Anywhere that i can get update return for primary key ?

```
$update = DB::table($table)
            ->where('userid', '=', Session::get('userid'))
            ->update_get_id(Input::all());
```

The value only will return 1 , mean to success. 
Anyone have solution to get update return primary id?

Is it possible i create another function in query.php for new function update_get_id ?
Thank you.

Comment: There is no such function.  Can you not just get the ID from the table first and then update?  This is all such a function would be able to do anyway.

Comment: Is the ID expected to change on update or something? You already have the ID with Session::get('userid') in the example you posted, I can't see why you would need that value returned unless you expected it to change, and if it's going to change, that indicates an issue with your database schema in my opinion.

Comment: I want to get the primary key number from the table which update. This id might help me to record a system log, so i need the id which have do update, insert or delete.

Comment: You could do this... $primarykey = DB::table($table)->where('userid', '=', Session::get('userid'))->only('id');

Comment: AW, thank you, i think temporary i will use your solution, just it might be process 2 time database, the propose for my question is done everyone in one process and can get the primary key value. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah I looked quickly into the Fluent source and it relies on the PDO method lastInsertId when using insert_get_id, and there is no PDO method to handle retrieving the ID after updating, so I feel like even if you were to extend that class and add a new method that does what you want, it would still involve 2 queries.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this with ordinary MySQL, is to let my table have a unique index, and then use an insert statement that uses the built-in last_insert_id() like so:

```
... on duplicate key update id = last_insert_id(id)
```

, then the insert_id should reflect the affected row.

I seem to remember having read that Eloquent currently doesn't have any out-of-the-box support for something like this via the api-methods, but maybe it is possible to create a raw sql statement that can do this trick.

It would probably take more time to implement such custom functionality than use some of the previous suggestions in the comments